# How to view the get shorlink and view post button when creating a post?

Tags: php, wordpress

I created a post in wordpress by clicking post in wordpress. after clicking publish, a link called permalink appears below the post title in the created post near the permalink , the view post and get shortlink button is not visible. Why is it like that ? Can anyone tell a solution ?

Screenshot:

[image]

---

[image]

This is my dashboard post view.

Comment: Can you share screenshot please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress has changed add/edit screen from latest 4.4 version. View post and get shortlink button is not visible anymore. To view post, you can click on the link shown and shortlink button is not visible anymore.

In addition to the View Post button, the Get shortlink button is also removed. The button shows up if you’re using a custom shortlink and can be re-enabled using code or some plugin. For most users, the Edit button is the only one they’ll see between the post title and content box.

[image]

For more details : http://wptavern.com/wordpress-4-4-removes-the-view-post-and-get-shortlink-buttons-from-the-post-editor